# Pinch to grow/shrink the size of a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've a few button on my screen which can be moved around ok, but I was wondering has anybody ever implemented a pinch gesture on a button to shink and grow the button?

If anybody has any ideas/help/examples of implementing this kind of functionality it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use an image, as a button?Then attach the touches directly to the image? Making the image act as a button. This isn't the most elegant way, but it's simple and fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a UIPinchGestureRecogniser to the button, and then apply it's scale property as a transform on the button's frame.

I don't have sample code, but that is the area I would look at to accomplish this.